# What is preventing a newform from getting the column descriptions updated?

Tags: 2013, content-type, site-column

- I have a modified contact list in a subsite template.
- The contact list has content type management activated
- the default content type is a modified *contact* (*mc* for brevity)
- the *mc* is defined on sitecollection level
- the *mc* is derived from the default *contact* type
- the *mc* has some additional columns
- the additional columns are defined on sitecollection level, too.

I want to change the *description* text of my additional columns, because the description appears in the newform of the modified contact list when I add an entity of this special content type.

For this purpose I instantiated my template, tried to change the description in several ways and wanted to save it as a site template again.

But neither editing the column nor editing the content type will effect the description text of the newform. It still keeps the old description.

*updated section*
I also removed the content type from the list and added it again to the list, but the outcome is the same. So I assume, the description isn't updated in the original content type either. What should i try next?

- delete the library and rebuild it? I want to avoid this, because this breaks another site with four extra views. I also can assume that this won't do the trick as removal and re-adding the content type did not do the trick either.
- delete the columns from the content type at sitecollection level and add them again? I'm in fear of side effects...
- ...?

*update*
When I edit the content type starting from the list, I get

```
ctype=0x010600E9E10C81D859A24A8F4C897C7EF06DBE0094EE07B8B611084A91895B94E6D83B410024B462919470EC47A9D81A80F6968174
```

from the url and if I edit it from the SC settings I get

```
ctype=0x010600E9E10C81D859A24A8F4C897C7EF06DBE0094EE07B8B611084A91895B94E6D83B41
```

which seems fairly identical except the appendix.

At the intermediate levels (subsite, subsubsite) I can't edit the CT.

I noticed that the different comments seem to stem from the site column. If I edit the column from the list, the url looks like this (CR inserted by me to increase readability)

```
(common parts removed)?CloseOnCancel=1&
Field=Demand&
Source=%2F
content%2F
10003931%2FSO%2FTPRV1%2E1%2F%5Flayouts%2F15%2F
ManageContentTypeField%2Easpx%3F
ctype%3D0x010600E9E10C81D859A24A8F4C897C7EF06DBE0094EE07B8B611084A91895B94E6D83B410024B462919470EC47A9D81A80F6968174%26
List%3D801329a1%2D5387%2D4a39%2D98cf%2D030e90af9cbd%26
Field%3DDemand%26
```

Fid%3D%257Ba9aad1a1%252Ded7b%252D4520%252Da069%252D4bd419b08883%257D

in contrast to editing it from the SC level:

```
(common parts removed)?CloseOnCancel=1&
Field=Demand&
Source=%2F
content%2F
10003931%2F%5F
layouts%2F15%2F
ManageContentTypeField%2Easpx%3F
ctype%3D0x010600E9E10C81D859A24A8F4C897C7EF06DBE0094EE07B8B611084A91895B94E6D83B41%26
Field%3DDemand%26
Fid%3D%257Ba9aad1a1%252Ded7b%252D4520%252Da069%252D4bd419b08883%257D
```

And that is, where the description differs. When I edited the site column on SC level I selected to update all list-columns, of course. But with no effect.

**Update**
I compared the column IDs using Get-PnPField in PowerShell and there's no difference between the list and the sitecollection.

Comment: try to update the MC on the Sitecollection. Make sure you have the push down changes option checked. Also make sure the CT-IDs are correct to see it. Make sure the list level is a child of the site level (post CT-ID's for all levels)

Comment: @HeikoHatzfeld_MSFT I did more tests and expanded the question.

Comment: I created a subsite, a new CT and with a new site field, added a list with that CT on a subsite, updated the field and it worked… So goto powershell, fetch the list and get the schema of the field from the fields collection. You should see a fieldID in there. Make sure its the same ID as the site column

Comment: @HeikoHatzfeld_MSFT I found out how to retrieve the ID of the list column but fail to get it from the site columns. How do I get that using Powershell? I tried to use "Get-PnPField" on SC level with and without "-InSiteHierarchy" but only get an error.